# Javascript: Text area last character is not being capitalized

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

Editing a Shopify app. Last character in the text area does not get capitalized on the label picture unless you click outside of text area.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#cstedit-addembossing').keyup(function() {
        this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea maxlength="10" data-area="back" class="customify-text" data-target="addembossing" id="cstedit-addembossing" placeholder="Write a name, special date, quote, and the list goes on"></textarea>
```

Comment: Your code works as expected in latest Firefox/Windows.

Comment: Maybe Shopify is "helping" you in some way?

Comment: Code works in latest Chrome/Windows, too.

Comment: instead of using javascript, can't you just add a `text-transform: uppercase;` style to the `textarea`?

Comment: @zgood I have tried adding that to the text area style, it only changes the text in the text area and not on the label image.

Comment: The code does work standalone but not on the website OP provided. Try the 'change' event instead of keyup. Or make your code force a refresh to them after changing the value. Seems like their event listener is firing before yours is which changing the text late.

Comment: @Daryll Tried the 'change' event instead of keyup. It still doesn't work. The text area doesn't get capitalized either when I use this function. Not sure how I would do the refresh

Comment: For now maybe hack something like `document.body.focus(); this.focus();` to simulate a click off the element and back onto it.

Comment: @Daryll  added that in before this.value = this.value.toUpperCase(); still doesn't work. But I think your on to something. When you type fast a lot of characters don't get capitalized on the photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably are looking for a different event than `keyup`. `input` works best for what you are trying to do imo.

```
$(function() {
    $('#cstedit-addembossing').on("input", function() {
        this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes! Amazing. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
// those listeners are added by customizer-final-v33.js
foo.addEventListener('change', e => display.textContent = foo.value);
foo.addEventListener('input', e => display.textContent = foo.value);

// this is basically your listener
foo.addEventListener('keyup', e => foo.value = foo.value.toUpperCase());
```

```html
<textarea id="foo"></textarea>
<hr />
<h1 id="display">Type and texarea will update this text.</h1>
```

To fix that, here you go:

```js
// those listeners are added by customizer-final-v33.js
foo.addEventListener('change', e => display.textContent = foo.value);
foo.addEventListener('input', e => display.textContent = foo.value);

// this is basically a working version your listener
foo.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  foo.value = foo.value + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toUpperCase();
  foo.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('input', { bubbles: true }));
})
```

```html
<textarea id="foo"></textarea>
<hr />
<h1 id="display">Type and texarea will update this text.</h1>
```